# Multiple anchor tag

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the red lines in-between "google links" but I still want the border color to be red.
How do I do it?
Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Website</title>
</head>
<body>
 <style>
 a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:tahoma;
    background:black;
    padding-top:2px;
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    padding-left:0px;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin-left:0px;}
 </style>
 <a href="https://www.google.co.in">google</a><a href="https://www.google.co.in">google</a><a href="https://www.google.co.in">google</a><a href="https://www.google.co.in">google</a><a href="https://www.google.co.in">google</a>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You mean something like ***[THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Z25x2/)***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set seperate border attributes for each `a` element like this:

```
a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:tahoma;
    background:black;
    padding-top:2px;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    padding-left:0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    margin-left:0px;
}

a:last-child{
    border-right:solid 1px red;
}

a:first-child{       
    border-left:solid 1px red;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K2MCX/5/)

Comment: +1 I have created same fiddle but then found this post before I post  :)

Comment: This happened to me hundred times ;) Thx @MarmiK

Comment: Your code worked perfectly fine, although i had to use the div tag to move all my anchors to a bit left because the red line in the left of the first child didn't show up. I wonder why that happened? Also I got to know about as to what is last and first child. Thank you.

Comment: Probably you set `margin:0` and `padding:0` somewhere in your css. Can not be 100% sure without see your entire code. You can use this `margin-left: 10px;` like this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/K2MCX/10/

Comment: I sure did set my margin and padding 0px. That caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Kden/1/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Kden/2/)

```
<div style="border:1px solid red;">
  <a href="https://www.google.co.in">google</a>
  <a href="https://www.google.co.in">google</a>
  <a href="https://www.google.co.in">google</a>
  <a href="https://www.google.co.in">google</a>
  <a href="https://www.google.co.in">google</a>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use pseudo classes and remove your left and right border from a.

```
a {
    border-right:none;
    border-left:none;
}
a:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid red;
}
a:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid red;
}
```

[See here for a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Callie_/x5C28/)

Comment: Those are not pseudo-elements, they are pseudo-**classes**

Comment: @Paulie_D Yeah, your right! I didn't know there was a difference but I googled it and found what the difference is! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap a div around your anchor tags and set the border to that div.

```
<div id="wrap">
    <a href="https://www.google.co.in">google</a>
    <a href="https://www.google.co.in">google</a>
    <a href="https://www.google.co.in">google</a>
    <a href="https://www.google.co.in">google</a>
    <a href="https://www.google.co.in">google</a>
</div>
```

Use `display:inline-block;` that your width is as big as your anchor tags.

Have a look at **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yZemS/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Border-color will help you

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NW3QZ/8/)

CODE :

```
 a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:tahoma;
    background:black;
    padding-top:2px;
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    padding-left:0px;    
    margin-left:0px; 
    border-color:red;
}
```